# TYPO3 Extbase: How to access "modified" flag of my object property?

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-flow

I frequently use the Extbase DebugUtility (`Tx_Extbase_Utility_Debugger::var_dump($object)`).
It displays additional data for each property, especially the "modified" flag - see screenshot.

How can I access this "meta property" from within my controller (updateAction)?
I tried `$object->getProperty->isModified` and other combinations, to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method `$yourObject->_isDirty("propertyName")` which returns true if it has been modified (see [documentation](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_object_1_1_abstract_domain_object.html#a5ef6e3e38c04c376fc641ac34a36f0ea)).

If your property is a collection itself, then just use `$yourObject->getWhatevers()->_isDirty()` (see [documentation](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_object_storage.html#aa95b2ae648ac3c4c52baaa6ec20afcb3)).

Comment: Also very helpful: The sibling function `_memorizeCleanState()`. I think I can use that to compare previous to modified values. Thanks Michael.

Comment: Update: in a current project, I'm accessing the unmodified value with: 
`$oldValue = $object->_getCleanProperty('value');`